# HTML JavaScript React: Front-End React Component Throwing react-dom.development.js:506 Warning

Tags: html, reactjs, render, descendant

I have rendered a front-end react / redux component using JSX syntax.  It executes but throws the following warning in my console:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getUsers, deleteUserThunk} from '../store/allUsers'
import {updateUserThunk, fetchSingleUser} from '../store/singleUser'
// Status Filter import BeerFilter from './BeerFilter'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import {UncontrolledCollapse} from 'reactstrap'

export class AllUsers extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showForm: false,
      stat: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      this.props.fetchInitialUsers()
      this.props.deleteUserThunk()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  clickHandlerOne() {
    let hidden = this.state.showForm
    this.setState({
      showForm: !hidden
    })
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    //console.log('event.target', event.target)
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }

  async handleSubmit(userId) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const updatedUser = {
      id: userId,
      isAdmin: this.state.stat
    }

    // console.log('UPDATE USER', updatedUser)

    await this.props.updateUserThunk(updatedUser)
    this.props.fetchInitialUsers()
  }

  render() {
    const users = this.props.users
    // console.log('PROPS', this.props)
    console.log('USERS', this.props.users)

    return (
      <div>
        {/* <div className="options">
          <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="">Sort By...</option>
            <option value="priceHighToLow">Price (high to low)</option>
            <option value="priceLowToHigh">Price (low to high)</option>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
          </select>

          <BeerFilter />
          </div> */}

        <div className="flex-cards">
          {users.map(user => (
            <Card style={{width: '18rem'}} key={user.id}>
              {/* delete thunk */}
              <span>
                <p>
                  <Button
                    id={`delete${user.id}`}
                    variant="danger"
                    onClick={() => this.props.deleteUserThunk(user.id)}
                  >
                    X
                  </Button>
                </p>
              </span>

              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>User Id: {user.id}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  <div>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <div className="highlight">
                          <img src={user.imageUrl} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="details">
                          <p>Username: {user.username}</p>
                          <p>User Email: {user.email}</p>
                          <p>Admin Status: {user.isAdmin ? 'true' : 'false'}</p>
                          <p>
                            Created Date:{' '}
                            {new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
                              month: 'short',
                              day: '2-digit',
                              year: 'numeric'
                            }).format(new Date(user.createdAt))}
                          </p>
                          <p />
                          <Button
                            id={`user${user.id}`}
                            onClick={() => {
                              this.clickHandlerOne()
                            }}
                            variant="outline-info"
                          >
                            Admin Status Toggle
                          </Button>
                          <UncontrolledCollapse toggler={`#user${user.id}`}>
                            {/* {this.state.showForm && (
                              <UpdateUserStatus userId={user.id} />
                            )} */}
                            <form onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit(user.id)}>
                              <div>
                                <span>
                                  <select
                                    name="stat"
                                    value={
                                      typeof user.isAdmin === 'string'
                                        ? this.state.isAdmin
                                        : user.isAdmin
                                    }
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                  >
                                    <option value="true">true</option>
                                    <option value="false">false</option>
                                  </select>
                                </span>

                                <p />
                                <span>
                                  <p>
                                    {/* */}
                                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                                  </p>
                                </span>
                              </div>
                            </form>
                          </UncontrolledCollapse>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    users: state.allUsers
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    loadSingleUser: id => dispatch(fetchSingleUser(id)),
    updateUserThunk: updatedUser => dispatch(updateUserThunk(updatedUser)),
    //getSortedBeers: (sortBy, beers) => dispatch(sortBeers(sortBy, beers)),
    fetchInitialUsers: () => dispatch(getUsers()),
    deleteUserThunk: userId => dispatch(deleteUserThunk(userId))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AllUsers)
```

In my web page I (not always but usually) have to click the edit button twice for my order status to update and render on my page. I'm wondering if the warning has anything to do with this.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  I am very new to this type of coding so specificity in responses would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few changes that I would make in addition to addressing your console error.

1. Bind `this` to `clickHandlerOne`
2. Don't use `<p>` tags for the sake of adopting their styling. Example:

   This makes sense to me. It's a paragraph of text.

   ```
   <p>Username: {user.username}</p>
   ```

   This doesn't make sense to me. I think you're wanting a `<button>` with certain spacing styles:

   ```
   <span>
     <p>
       <Button
         id={`delete${user.id}`}
         variant="danger"
         onClick={() => this.props.deleteUserThunk(user.id)}
       >
         X
       </Button>
     </p>
   </span>
   ```

Try out this code and see how it works:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getUsers, deleteUserThunk } from "../store/allUsers";
import { updateUserThunk, fetchSingleUser } from "../store/singleUser";
// Status Filter import BeerFilter from './BeerFilter'
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import { UncontrolledCollapse } from "reactstrap";

export class AllUsers extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showForm: false,
      stat: ""
    };
    this.clickHandlerOne = this.clickHandlerOne.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      this.props.fetchInitialUsers();
      this.props.deleteUserThunk();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  clickHandlerOne() {
    const hidden = this.state.showForm;
    this.setState({
      showForm: !hidden
    });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    //console.log('event.target', event.target)
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  async handleSubmit(userId) {
    // event.preventDefault(); // I don't think you ave an `event` in scope here

    const updatedUser = {
      id: userId,
      isAdmin: this.state.stat
    };

    // console.log('UPDATE USER', updatedUser)

    await this.props.updateUserThunk(updatedUser);
    this.props.fetchInitialUsers();
  }

  render() {
    const users = this.props.users;
    // console.log('PROPS', this.props)
    console.log("USERS", this.props.users);

    return (
      <div>
        {/* <div className="options">
          <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="">Sort By...</option>
            <option value="priceHighToLow">Price (high to low)</option>
            <option value="priceLowToHigh">Price (low to high)</option>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
          </select>

          <BeerFilter />
          </div> */}

        <div className="flex-cards">
          {users.map(user => (
            <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }} key={user.id}>
              {/* delete thunk */}
                <div>
                  <Button
                    id={`delete${user.id}`}
                    variant="danger"
                    onClick={() => this.props.deleteUserThunk(user.id)}
                  >
                    X
                  </Button>
                </div>

              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>User Id: {user.id}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  <div>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <div className="highlight">
                          <img src={user.imageUrl} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="details">
                          <p>Username: {user.username}</p>
                          <p>User Email: {user.email}</p>
                          <p>Admin Status: {user.isAdmin ? "true" : "false"}</p>
                          <p>
                            Created Date:{" "}
                            {new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB", {
                              month: "short",
                              day: "2-digit",
                              year: "numeric"
                            }).format(new Date(user.createdAt))}
                          </p>
                          <Button
                            id={`user${user.id}`}
                            onClick={() => {
                              this.clickHandlerOne();
                            }}
                            variant="outline-info"
                          >
                            Admin Status Toggle
                          </Button>
                          <UncontrolledCollapse toggler={`#user${user.id}`}>
                            {/* {this.state.showForm && (
                              <UpdateUserStatus userId={user.id} />
                            )} */}
                            <form onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit(user.id)}>
                              <div>
                                  <select
                                    name="stat"
                                    value={
                                      typeof user.isAdmin === "string"
                                        ? this.state.isAdmin
                                        : user.isAdmin
                                    }
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                  >
                                    <option value="true">true</option>
                                    <option value="false">false</option>
                                  </select>

                                  <div>
                                    {/* */}
                                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                            </form>
                          </UncontrolledCollapse>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    users: state.allUsers
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    loadSingleUser: id => dispatch(fetchSingleUser(id)),
    updateUserThunk: updatedUser => dispatch(updateUserThunk(updatedUser)),
    //getSortedBeers: (sortBy, beers) => dispatch(sortBeers(sortBy, beers)),
    fetchInitialUsers: () => dispatch(getUsers()),
    deleteUserThunk: userId => dispatch(deleteUserThunk(userId))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AllUsers);
```

To get the styles that you were relying on from the `<p>`, you can [inline styles](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style), or use CSS via the [`className`](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) prop.

There's also a few CSS-in-JS libraries to be aware of, such as [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/).

Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: this is amazing!  thank you so much for the detailed response... it's working now!

Comment: you seem like quite the expert at this.  Do you mind if I ask you a follow-up question? My deleteUserThunk doesn't appear to work.  I've been troubleshooting it for hours, but when I click on my web page's delete button, nothing happens.  Link to SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049013/javascript-react-redux-cannot-delete-item-on-web-page-back-end-delete-route/58049244#58049244

Answer (score 0):

`<Card.Text>` renders a `<p>` and you have plenty of `<div>`'s nested there.

I also spotted an issue in `handleSubmit` function. You are calling `event.preventDefault()` but you are not passing the `event` is undefined.

Comment: thanks for response Matthew ... I don't quite understand what you mean by the handleSubmit section; would you mind elaborating?  Where should I be passing the event?  (sorry, I'm very new to this)

Comment: `handleSubmit` is a function that you are using. the `event` is not defined in that scope.